# Where should I put code in my Android app which I want to be run only when the Activity is stopped because it will be recreated?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I would like a piece of code to run in case the Activity is stopped because - for example - an orientation change happens and a new Activity is created. But I don't want it to run in case the Activity is stopped because the user navigates away and then comes back.

To be more precise: 
I have a timer which counts back. If the time passes, the game is over. So when the user navigates away, I don't want the timer to stop. But if the user rotates the device, a new Activity is created and the timer is recreated, and I would like the old Activity's timer to stop.

Comment: try to write that code in service and startService() on your scenario, onPause() method always called whenever user calls another activity or lost focus from that activity, try to implement your code or startService from onPause()

Comment: sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want this in the first place?

Comment: put the code in `onCreate()`, since `onCreate()` will be called on orientation changes or you can use `Loaders`, if you don't want to run the code, in-case it has not finished working before orientation change.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise when asking the question. I've just updated it.

Comment: use a bound service

Answer (score -2):

You can put your pice of code into the `onResume()` method by use the `@Override` annotation. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Your code here
}
```

Or use some of the other Android Lifecycle Methods of this [diagram](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/images/activity_lifecycle.png).